# Treeview not expanding horizontally to fit items

Tags: python, tkinter

The treeview is a child of root and I believe has space in which it can expand. Therefore, I expect it to dynamically expand horizontally when an item wider than its current width is added to it, as the frame widget does. Instead, it clips the end of item, obscuring it from view.

This code should reproduce the issue as I see it, which works on my machine with Python 3.9.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')

tree = ttk.Treeview(root)

parent = tree.insert('', 'end', text='123456789', open=False)
tree.insert(parent, 'end', text='123456789abcdefghijklmnop', open=False)
            
tree.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

An ideal solution would be a treeview that looks identical yet has attached a working horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question as I had been struggling with this for some time, with some questions/answers (on SO and elsewhere) indicating that there are potentially historic issues with tkinter's treeviews and horizontal scrolling.

I personally could not find a code example of a horizontally scrollable tkinter treeview, so hopefully this question and answer can save others time who are in a similar position. Please comment your thoughts on my attempt at a solution and answer yourself if you have a better one/I  missed something obvious. The code to my solution and a breakdown of it are below.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')

font = font.nametofont('TkDefaultFont')
custom_indent = 15
arrow_width = 20
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('Treeview', indent=custom_indent)

frame = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=0)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, highlightthickness=0)
scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)
tree = ttk.Treeview(scrollable_frame)
vert_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient='vertical', command=tree.yview)
tree.configure(yscrollcommand = vert_scrollbar.set)
hori_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient='horizontal', command=canvas.xview)
canvas.configure(xscrollcommand = hori_scrollbar.set)

scrollable_frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all')))

parent = tree.insert('', 'end', text='beginning of song', open=False, tags='folder')
child = tree.insert(parent, 'end', text='123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv', open=False, tags='folder')
tree.insert(child, 'end', text='end of story', open=False)

count = 0
for i in range(50):
    count += 1
    num = str(count)
    tree.insert(child, 'end', text=num, open=False)

def get_indent_lvl(item_id, tree):
    indent_lvl = 0
    parent_id = tree.parent(item_id)
    while parent_id:
        indent_lvl += 1
        parent_id = tree.parent(parent_id)
    return indent_lvl
    
def children_width_check(event):
    tree = event.widget
    item_id = tree.selection()[0]
    child_item_ids = tree.get_children(item_id)
    for id in child_item_ids:
        item = tree.item(id)
        child_width = int(font.measure(item['text'])) + 30 # 30 is optional padding for aesthetic reasons
        indent_lvl = get_indent_lvl(id, tree)
        if 'folder' in item['tags']:
            child_width += arrow_width
        else:
            child_width += custom_indent
        child_width += arrow_width * indent_lvl
        col_width = tree.column('#0')['width']
        if child_width > col_width:
            canvas.itemconfigure('scrollable_frame', width=child_width)
            
def sibling_width_check(event):
    tree = event.widget
    item_id = tree.selection()[0]
    sibling_item_ids = tree.get_children(tree.parent(item_id))
    indent_lvl = get_indent_lvl(item_id, tree)
    sibling_widths = []
    for id in sibling_item_ids:
        item = tree.item(id)
        sibling_width = int(font.measure(item['text'])) + 30
        if 'folder' in item['tags']:
            sibling_width += arrow_width
        else:
            sibling_width += custom_indent
        sibling_width += arrow_width * indent_lvl
        sibling_widths.append(sibling_width)
    if max(sibling_widths) > 200:    
        canvas.itemconfigure('scrollable_frame', width=max(sibling_widths))
    else:
        canvas.itemconfigure('scrollable_frame', width=200)
        
tree.bind('<<TreeviewOpen>>', children_width_check)
tree.bind('<<TreeviewClose>>', sibling_width_check)

frame.pack()
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
vert_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
hori_scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor='nw', tags='scrollable_frame')
tree.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

tree.update()
canvas.configure(width=tree.winfo_width(), height=tree.winfo_height())

root.mainloop()
```

### Code breakdown

Creates a frame (`frame`) to hold the scrollbars and treeview together (positioned via grid to produce the correct scrollbar layout).

Next we create a scrollable frame within the canvas. I borrowed this code from [https://blog.teclado.com/tkinter-scrollable-frames](https://blog.teclado.com/tkinter-scrollable-frames/), it creates a canvas of fixed size within which sits a variably sized frame through which it scrolls. I am unsure exactly how this works, yet it appears to. The treeview is added to `scrollable_frame`.

Next, some items are added to the treeview. For reasons later explained, it is required that items that have/will have children are given a tag of 'folder'.

Next, functions are bound to the events that are fired whenever an item of the treeview is opened/closed. Specifically, these functions estimate the width the treeview should be post the opening/closing event and then set `scrollable_frame` to have this width. Due to the treeview being packed in this frame with `expand=1, fill='both'` it resizes with `scrollable_frame`.

When the size of `scrollable_frame` exceeds that of the canvas (which is forced to be the default height/width of the initial treeview) the scrollbars are triggered.

The estimation of the width the treeview (contained in `children_width_check()` and `sibling_width_check`) is not perfect, relying on my estimate for the pixel width of the arrow-toggle to open/close treeview items. A buffer of 30px is added to the width estimation to be safe, and also for aesthetic reasons. A 'folder' tag is required on each treeview item with children so the estimate accounts for the arrow-toggle width.